Generate c++ class from a function
There's a framework with a strange API. To use it, I need to write a wrapper class around a function and use the class to interact with the framework.

void f(
  std::optional<int> i,
  std::optional<double> j) {
    something ();
}

class WrapF {
  void wf() {  f(nullopt, nullopt); }
  void wf(int i) {  f(i, nullopt); }
  void wf(double j) {  f(nullopt, j); }
  void wf(int i, double j) {  f(i, j); }
};


I want to generate this class because it becomes tedious with more arguments. Not all arguments are optional.
Is this possible at all, with just the language features?

And what should the class look like for f(std::optional<int> i, std::optional<double> j, std::optional<int> k)?

whats wrong with what you have already? YOu have to do this for many different types f ? Or you need many different wrappers for the same type? Both?

Do you want 2^N overloads? Would it be ok to write a single template function that behaves equivalently?

What are your degrees of freedom with respect to WrapF? Do you need these overloads exactly or will any set do?

Is there any reason you can't parse the API files and auto-generate C++ wrappers from them in advance, rather than trying to do this at compile-time?

@JackAidley, the reason is that it is a requirement, but if it is possible to do it with templates then I think code generation would be at best a temporary implementation.

@Botje, should match exactly because the framework instantiates everything.

@CompuChip, I really don't know :) but I would probably try a wrapper for one of the args.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, this is an RPC integration API, there are no limits.

Assuming there are no same types in parameters, with template, you might do:
template <auto func>
struct WrapF;

template <typename... Ts, void (*func)(std::optional<Ts>...)>
struct WrapF<func>
{
private:
    template <typename... Us>
    static constexpr bool is_valid()
    {
        [[maybe_unused]]auto compute_index = []<typename U>(std::type_identity<U>){
            std::array<bool, sizeof...(Ts)> a{{ std::is_same_v<U, Ts>... }};
            return std::distance(a.begin(), std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), true));
        };
        std::array<std::ptrdiff_t, sizeof...(Us)> indexes {{compute_index(std::type_identity<Us>{})...}};

        if constexpr (sizeof...(Us) != 0) {
            if (indexes.back() == sizeof...(Ts)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return std::is_sorted(indexes.begin(), indexes.end());
    }


    template <typename T, typename... Us>
    static std::optional<T> get_optional(std::tuple<Us&...> tuple)
    {
        if constexpr ((std::is_same_v<T, Us> || ...)) {
            return std::get<T&>(tuple);
        } else {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
public:    
    template <typename... Us>
    requires (is_valid<Us...>())
    void wf(Us... args) {
        f(get_optional<Ts>(std::tie(args...))...);
    }
};

Demo
Notice that it is not equivalent to your code, as convertion/promotion is not allowed, i.e, WrapF{}.wf(4, 2) works on your side as WrapF{}.wf(4, 2.), but mine rejects it.

Thanks, this is super cool and helped me a lot.

Is it supposed to be easy to have a fixed, but templated, last argument to wf?

You can get last argument of parameter pack with std::get<sizeof...(Us) - 1>(std::tie(args...))
